# Generating DDL from YAML using Spring boot

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot, yaml, ddl

Is it possible to write a **YAML** file with a database description(table names, columns, data types,...), then use **spring boot** to (first) create the **DDL** of the database, then to create the database itself?
I will appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

JPA can generate database schema from your model.
Please read for example this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-generate-db-schema

Comment: So, I need to generate classes from yaml file (that contains the database description), then use the mentioned example to create the DDL, right?

Comment: You can also provide SQL script. As far as I know Liquibase can create db schema directly from yaml. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html